# Cannot access Gitlab repo from browser or from terminal

Tags: windows, git, gitlab

I cannot access Gitlab from the browser.
I am getting the following message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> **gitlab.com** took too long to respond.
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
> - ERR_TIMED_OUT

I am not able to use **git pull origin master** and **git push -u origin master** from the terminal.
It is showing the following error message:

```
**fatal: unable to access "https://gitlab.com/myproject.git/" : OpenSSL SSL_connect: SS_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.com:443**
```

Help me to fix the isssue,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS settings, can you reach other sites? This doesn't seem to be a `gitlab` specific problem.

Also, your remote URL seems quite weird. It's usually `gitlab.com/user/repo.git`

- Try other sites, do they work?
- Try acquiring the IP Address from gitlab using an online `whois` service. Does opening this IP work?
- Adjust your origin:

  git remote rm origin
  git remote add origin "https://username@gitlab.com/username/password.git"

Try this and report back if something worked.